# Chef bash resource, command attribute doesn't work

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I have a simple recipe that looks like this:

```
bash "create folder" do
  command "mkdir -p /home/user/folder"
  not_if {::File.directory?("/home/user/folder")}
end
```

It doesn't work. It says that it's executing, but it doesn't create the folder. If I change `bash` to `execute` then it works. If I change `command` to `code` then it works. But the [bash](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_bash.html) and [execute](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_execute.html) docs have literally the same specs on `command`.

Am I doing something wrong or are the docs wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the attributes documentation of the [Bash resource](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_bash.html#attributes):

> **code**: A quoted (” ”) string of code to be executed.
>   **command**: The name of the command to be executed. Default value: the name of the resource block (see Syntax section above).

This, the command attribute is just the name of the command, not the full code to run. With the bash resource (and all the other [script resources](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_script.html)), you should use the `code` attribute to send the code to be executed.

The correct resource definition is thus:

```
bash "create folder" do
  code "mkdir -p /home/user/folder"
  not_if {::File.directory?("/home/user/folder")}
end
```

In fact, the contents of the `command` attribute is not used there anywhere, it's just there because the script resource inherits from the `execute` resource and thus inherits all its possible attributes.

As a final remark, to create a directory, you should use the actual idiomatic `directory` resource built-in to Chef instead of a bash script like this:

```
directory "/home/user/folder" do
  recursive true
end
```

Comment: You should use the Chef idioms when using Chef. That will make your life and that of others much easier as things are consistent in Chef. If you want to write bash scripts, you could do that and not use Chef. But if you want to use Chef, you should follow the conventions. The built-in resources have idempotence (i.e. repeatability) built-in. In case of the directory resource, you can also set the owner and permissions as well as use notifications if required.

Comment: Regarding readability and conventions: if I see a `directory` resource, I know immediately that it creates a directory. If I see your bash resource, I would always have to manually read the code (and the guards) to understand what it is doing. Once you start to do more complex things than creating a directory, your bash snippets will get out of hand.

Comment: If you just want to write bash, you should use fss. If you care at all about the idempotency and convergence of your scripts, you should use Chef or Puppet.

Comment: Eh, if you see a resource named "create folder" or if you see a `mkdir` command, you should also know immediately what it does. I use chef resources when it's easier than writing the corresponding bash script, like for transferring files and starting services, but one-liners that are already idempotent (the `-p` option ensures that, I don't actually need the guard) are quicker than reading through broken documentation. I understand your point in general, but bash handles file system interaction just fine, and I can easily ensure idempotence with guards, just as they were intended.

Comment: Is the `execute` resource translating its `command` into code behind the scenes? That's weird that script resources inherit the attribute but not its functionality.

Comment: Basically, the script providers take the `code`, write it to a temporary file and then using the `execute` provider to run that script using the selected interpreter. That's why you can't override the command: the generated script is the command.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of bash is `Use to run a script`.

The default behavior of execute is `Use to run a command`.

You are running a command, not a script, so it makes sense you should be using a code block or using execute instead. The difference between the two is... not well defined in the docs. I have found at least 3 or 4 examples in the docs that were outright wrong and submitted corrections, some of which still haven't been made.

Comment: Ok, I see that difference now, but both of them say "`name` is the name of the resource block; when the `command` attribute is not specified as part of a recipe, `name` is also the name of the command to be executed". And both of them have the same text for `:nothing` right under `:run`. It's frustrating.